# Table structure in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm in the early stages of creating a database using MySQL and PHP and would like some advice please.  I have started to collate the data and would like to start typing it into .csv files ready to import into my tables. Before I do, I'm unsure how to layout my structured columns and tables properly.

Ok, I'll try my best to make clear what I'm trying to create. I'd have my home page structure where you have a choice of selecting a list of players by season or by an A-Z list of all-time players. Once you click on a specific player from the list of players it would show something like this for their player profile: http://stats.touch-line.com/playerdet.asp?playerid=41472&cust=2&lang=0&FromSTR=TRUE&compid=&teamid=1&H2H=

How many tables would I need to create?

A player table with **playerID,playerName,playerDOB,playerBirthplace,playerPosition** etc.

A team table with **teamID,teamName,teamNickname,teamGround,teamFounded** etc.

A season table with **seasonID,playerID,teamID,playerApps,playerGoals**?

Or is there a quicker, more efficient way without the need to use so many tables to link the data? Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: You've got a good start, but consider that `playerPosition` might change through a player's career or even within a season. "center" on team #1, "goalie" on team #2, and maybe "benchwarmer" on team #3.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc. ;) playerPosition aside, I'm just trying to figure the most efficient way of combining the data. Ideally on the player profile it would have SEASON | TEAM NAME | APPS | GOALS but I'm unsure how I would store the data in a table. With so many entries would it run efficiently? Or would I need to create a table for each season?

Comment: SQL databases run efficiently on tables containing millions of rows, so don't worry about 'so many entries'. What is important, though, is getting the data structure correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many tables do I need to create?

The short answer is: one table for each "entity" type. An entity can be defined as a person, place, thing, concept or event, which can be uniquely identified, is of interest to the business, and we can store information about.

One key to database design is data analysis (Richard Perkinson "Data Analysis: The Key to Database Design", QED c.1993)

You've identified some of the important entities in your model: player, team, season. There may be some other key entities that are missing, which may be discovered later.

The attributes of each entity need to be identified, and should be dependent on the key of the entity, and not some other key. (Every attribute should be dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me Codd.)

You also need to identify the relationships that exist between the entities. Can a player be a member of more than one team? Can a player have more than one position? If a player is traded (moves from one team to another), how will that be represented in the model?

Where we encounter "many-to-many" relationships, those are represented in a separate relationship tables. Repeating attributes also get broken into separate child tables.

It's important that you get the model right, before you start combining multiple entities into the same table. Optimization usually results in a broken model; it usually doesn't fix a model that doesn't work.

Databases are designed to handle large number of rows efficiently, when the queries are in line with the model. Databases with dozens of tables can run very efficiently, and run more efficiently than databases with fewer tables.

I'd be more concerned with getting a database design that works, than I would be concerned with optimizing a design that doesn't work.

Comment: Nice answer! Can you clarify what you mean by "the attributes should be dependent on the key"?

Comment: @ravloony: we need to make sure that the values stored in a column are determined by the key of the table, to avoid redundancy and update anomalies. As an example, we don't want to store an attribute of the `team` on the `player` table, where it would be repeated for each player on the team. (That example isn't that good, because it's pretty obvious.) As another example,  `dateJoinedTeam` wouldn't really be an attribute of `player`, it's really an attribute on the relationship between `player` and `team`. It's a process of working every column that's needed, and answering the right questions.

Comment: As an example from the OP columns, is the `playerPosition` an attribute of the player (like DOB and and Birthplace are), OR is it an attribute of the relationship between `player` and `team`. Could a `player` be a first string forward on one team, but a second string guard on another team? (I don't have the answer to that question, but having an answer such as "a player has exactly one position, no more, no less and is independent of which team they are on" vs. "a player can hold more than one position, on the same team".

Comment: @spencer7593 Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm beginning to understand the structuring more. For this case, the player can only play for one club team at a time and usually only plays in one position.  It's frustrating more than anything because I know exactly what layout I would like but I can't put it into practice.  I'll have to do more research and then once I've got some sample data in the right columns and tables... TRY and write some PHP script to display it all! Deep breaths! Thanks again. :)

Comment: @julescoco: the idea is to store 'transactional data' at the lowest, most atomic, layer: in this case, it would be at the level of each game. You would have a table where each row describes a game: team a, team b, date and other atomic data regarding the game itself. Then you would have another table where each row describes a player's role in that game: the player's id, the game's id, which team he was playing for, his position, how many goals he scored, how many minutes he played, etc. This allows you to sum data in the most flexible manner. Don't worry that there will be thousands of rows!

Comment: @No'amNewman Thanks for answering. It's a long process typing out all the game data so my primary aim now is to have an index page where visitors have a choice of selecting their team.  Then on the start page for each team, an A-Z list of players by season. Exactly like this: (http://www.evertonfc.com/stats/?mode=players). Once you click on the player name it would have another table with Season, Team Name, Apps, Goals like this (http://stats.touch-line.com/playerdet.asp?playerid=41472&cust=2).  My biggest problem now is the easiest way to structure the data into tables. Linking ID's etc.